# Recursive function in C returns value without a return

Tags: c, recursion, return, binary-search-tree

So I'm writing some binary search tree functions in C (here are the node structure and insert function which work perfectly):

```
typedef struct searchTreeNode {
    int data;
    struct searchTreeNode *left;
    struct searchTreeNode *right;
} STNode;


void insert(STNode **proot, int data) {

    STNode *node = *proot;
    if (!node) {
        *proot = newNode(data);
        return ;
    }
    if (data <= node -> data) insert(&(node -> left), data);
    else insert(&(node -> right), data);
}
```

And I found that the following recursive function for finding the max value of the tree works just fine even though just the last recursive call is actually returning an integer:

```
int max(STNode *node) {

    if (!node) return 0;
    if (!(node -> right)) return node -> data;
    max(node -> right);
}
```

This means, if I am not mistaken, that it does exactly the same as this:

```
int max(STNode *node) {

    if (!node) return 0;
    if (!(node -> right)) return node -> data;
    return max(node -> right);
}
```

Where the function now returns the value it gets from the next recursion call.

Is this a known behavior where the function returns the last returned value or am I missing something?

Here is my main function with some random numbers:

```
int main() {

    STNode *root = NULL;
    insert(&root, 10);
    insert(&root, 13);
    insert(&root, 14);
    insert(&root, 124);
    insert(&root, 1);
    insert(&root, 8);
    insert(&root, 3);

    printf("Max value: %d\n", max(root));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `max(node -> right);` does not do anything with the value returned by the recursive `max()`. So it isn't the same. It is a function that should return a value but does not.

Comment: The first version of `max` has undefined behavior. Your compiler could have [warned](https://godbolt.org/z/f8YjWjMh8) you about that.

Comment: @Bob__: The behavior of the first version of `max` is defined by the C standard; it does not have undefined behavior. The C standard does not require a function declared with a non-`void` return type to actually return a value. Only if the calling function attempts to use the value is the behavior not defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good to know, thanks, but I see a `printf("Max value: %d\n", max(root));` in `main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your first version of `max` does not `return` a value on all paths, it results in undefined behaviour when the caller tries to read that value. It is up to the compiler what to do out of that. It is not guaranteed that the compiler is inserting a `return` somewhere. You cannot rely on anything in that situation.

What de facto might happen on your specific platform is that the pathes

```
if (!node) return 0;
if (!(node -> right)) return node -> data;
```

write to a register where the value is returned. The recursive call `max(node -> right);` means that at the end one of the upper two `return`s will happen and the return value will be in the right register. So when `max` silently returns without an explicit `return ...;` the compiler might just issue a return machine code and leave the return register unchanged. This of course only happens because the recursive call to `max` is the last statement in your function (that modifies the return register).

But as said, please don't do that, it is undefined behavior and chances are high that it will cause you trouble in future.

Comment: “As your first version of `max` does not `return` a value on all paths, it has undefined behaviour” is not correct. The C standard permits a function declared with a non-`void` return type to return without return a value (by letting program control flow to the closing `}`). Only if the calling function attempts to use the value of the function is the behavior then undefined. An example of where this may be used is in a function such as `int GetSet(int option, int value)` that returns a stored setting if `option` is zero and sets the setting (with no return value) if `option` is non-zero.